# GWT add Widget to iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, iframe

Is there a solution to add a Widget to an iFrame in GWT?

The Widget itself needs to interact with the GWT code.

The purpose is to have a hidden iframe, which is used solely for printing purposes. I cannot just copy the inner content to that iframe and show because I have some canvas elements, that are not repainted.

Answer (score 0):

If you chose to represent the `iframe` as a GWT `Composite`, you can treat it like any other GWT component and add widgets to it.

You can read further on this approach on the [GWT blogspot's post on widget best practices](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2009/05/widget-best-practices-widget-building.html).